# Testing Node Application with mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have the following test application based on a template provided by openshift.

**server.js:**

```
var express = require('express');

exports.NodeTestApp = function () {
    self.cache_get = function (key) {
            return 'Would be a value here';
    };
}
```

**server_test.js:**

```
var server = require('../server');

describe('Server', function(){
    describe('Startup',function(){
        it('sets up routes during startup',function(){
            var app = server.NodeTestApp();
            app.cache_get('/');

            expect(app.routes.size).to.equals(5);
        })
    })
})
```

When I run this test I get an error message that cache_get is not defined.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache_get' of undefined
    at Context.<anonymous> (test/server_test.js:7:16)`

I would have thought that everything that is specified in the NodeTestApp function is available via variable app. IntelliJ even shows me the function as a valid call. Any idea why I get this error ?

Thanks in advance.
Oliver

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem with above code. To instantiate the app variable the new keyword has to be used. I didn't think that this is required as I would have thought its purely a function call and not a constructor call, which requires the new keyword. Below is the working code for your reference.

```
var app = new server.NodeTestApp();
```